# How do I use matplotlib to plot the data that I have acquired from my ADC? Nothing was plotted

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have acquired readings from my ADC (MCP3208), the full code is written below.

I can read my ADC values and even logged them into a .bat file and use GNUplot to plot the data but when I use this code nothing was plotted?

Edit: I've moved my t.append into my loop but I still have the same problem. No plot is shown.

Comment: Try using plot outside the loop

Comment: plt.show() is a blocking call. It shouldn't be used in a loop like that.

Comment: Thanks @Tino and user1558604, I noticed that when I was posting this question although now it still gives me a new problem where nothing is plotted

Comment: @HazmanHussin `t` list that you're using in your plot contains only one number and in doesn't make much sense. (if I haven't missed anything). Try printing out parameters that you use in `plt.plot()`, I think that it will be more clear then, because from your question it's hard to tell what exactly the result should look like.

Comment: @Tino I'm trying to plot value from ch0 which is `values[1]` against time which is `t_operating`. I tried `plt.plot(t_operating, values[1])` before this and it gave the same result --> nothing was plotted

Comment: @HazmanHussin Then you need to use `t.append(time.now())`  in loop to track operating time. (If it operates within loop?)

Comment: also why would you need to plot one value?

Comment: in `values[1]` you have only one (last) value - you try to plot one point so it can be not visible on plot. If you want to plot many points then you should keep them in different way - two dimensional array with `data[time][channel]` or `data[channel][time]`

Comment: @Tino I've moved them into the loop. I printed out the value of t_operating just now into my .bat file and it is not just one value. I have increasing values that was printed out in rows.

Comment: you have to also keep `values` in the same way - something like `all_values.append(values)`. In current code in every loop you create new `values` so you delete previous content - so finally you have only last content - single number in every channel.

Comment: OR you could create (before loop) separated lists for channels and inside loop do `channel1.append(values[1])`, `channel2.append(values[2])`. And later `plot(t, channel1)`

Comment: BTW: maybe after loop simply use `print(values)` to see what you get in this variable. Using `print()` helps to see/find problem - and it is called "print debuging"

Comment: @furas thank you soooo much! I've been stuck here for like 2 weeks on this. So the problem was I didn't know my values got overwritten! Problem solved!